# Разбить строчку на подстроки с lookahead lookbehind

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Помогите с регулярным выражение

Есть строка

```
<per.name>test jenkins<go <begin xml <per.street>else per.country>spring good
```

На выходе

```
<per.name>
test
jenkins
<go
<begin
xml
<per.street>
else 
per.country>
spring
good
```

Те по факту " " режет на подстроки, если символ < - это начало новой подстроки и он цепляется к ней, если > - то тоже новая подстрока, но он цепляется к старой

Comment: Пришла идея сделал проще заменил ">" на "> " и "<" на " <" и дальше сплит по пробелу

Answer (score 0):

например так

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = "<per.name>test jenkins<go <begin xml <per.street>else per.country>spring good";

my @r = split /\s|(?<=>)|(?=<)/xms, $s;

print "$_\n" for (@r);
```

Answer (score 0):

Дано:

```
<per.name>test jenkins<go <begin xml <per.street>else per.country>spring good
```

Подойдет такая регулярка:

```
@([<]*[\w.]++[>]*)@
```

или такая:

```
@([<]*[^<>\s]++[>]*)@
```

Совпадения:

```
[0] => <per.name>
[1] => test
[2] => jenkins
[3] => <go
[4] => <begin
[5] => xml
[6] => <per.street>
[7] => else
[8] => per.country>
[9] => spring
[10] => good
```